# Service Cloud Console - Record Page Layout

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, service-cloud-console

I'm trying to change the Page Layout for a Custom Object in the Console.
My profile is System Administrator with the Service Could User enabled.

Is there a way for changing the Page Layout for a Custom Object in the Console?

Comment: whats the issue you are facing? probably a screenshot could help to understand better

Comment: If you want a yes or no answer. The answer is yes.

Comment: @glls Thanks! I truly appreciate your time and effort .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to rhe documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accessing_layout_custom.htm&language=en_US&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.es%2F&type=0)
Long story short. Yes, it is possible.

> From the management settings for the object whose page layout you want
>   to edit, go to Page Layouts. Complete one of the following.If you have
>   “Customize Application” permission, open the page layout that you want
>   to customize for edit.If you have the “View Setup and Configuration”
>   permission, click the page layout that you want to view

Please make surte to refer to the H&T portal prior to asking a question for future reference and make sure you include a specific problem you are facing.